# 60 days Notice allowed for Month-to-Month rental in California?

Tags: california, residential-lease

Can a California landlord require 60 days notice on a month-to-month rental agreement?

Answer (score 1):

> Can a California landlord require 60 days notice on a month-to-month
>   rental agreement?

No. California legislation does not appear to recognize clauses which *require* a tenant's notice to exceed 30 days. See [Section 1946 of the California Civil Code](http://leginfo.legislature.ca.gov/faces/codes_displaySection.xhtml?lawCode=CIV&sectionNum=1946.):

> *[A]s to tenancies from month to month either of the parties may terminate the same by giving at least 30 days’ written notice [...].
>   It shall be competent for the parties to provide by an agreement at
>   the time the tenancy is created that a notice of the intention to
>   terminate the same may be given at any time not less than seven days
>   before the expiration of the term thereof.*

Thus, there being a provision that allows agreements to *reduce* the notice period down to seven days, but no provision allowing agreements to *stretch* the notice period, the legislative intent seemingly is to prevent a landlord from requiring a 60-day termination notice.

Comment: OP, this is the correct answer, pay no mind to the misinformed post, which I refuse to call an answer, from @Dale M.

Answer (score -2):

People can put whatever terms they like in a rental agreement. However, a requirement to give 60 days notice *ipso facto* means the lease is not “month-to-month”.

Comment: I suspect the real question is whether such terms would be *enforceable* under California law.

Comment: As usual, Dale's answer is completely false.